# Uploading to OpenStack Multipart With Path

Tags: java, openstack-swift, jclouds

I'm using java Jclouds to upload to a container inside an OpenStack Swift, the upload is going fine on the root, but when i pass a path(contains folders then the file), the file is uploaded but also creates another folder with the same name of the file. the original file name is **8mb.bin**

the code is:

```
try {
    ByteSource fileBytes = Files.asByteSource(file);
    File file = new File(filePath);
    String name = "test/test2/" + file.getName();
    Blob blob = blobStore.blobBuilder(name)
        .userMetadata(ImmutableMap.of("ContentType", contentType, "test", String.valueOf(test)))
        .payload(fileBytes)
        .contentLength(file.length())
        .contentType(contentType)
        .build();

    ///sednig the request
    blobStore.putBlob(ContainerName, blob, multipart());
    return contentLength;    
}
```

and in the designated path its like this:
[image]

the folder `8mb.bin` has the path inside it `/slo/1522766773.076000/8200000/33554432` and then a file called **00000000** with the same size of the original file size.

how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jclouds implements Swift multipart using [Static Large Objects](https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/overview_large_objects.html#module-swift.common.middleware.slo).  This has the limitation that parts exist in the same namespace as the manifest and modifying or deleting the parts invalidates the manifest.  [JCLOUDS-1285](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-1285) suggests putting the parts in another container to clean up object listing although this requires some extra logic for deletes and overwrites.